# DataGrid DatePickertemplate WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application and a problem with a DatePicker in a DataTemplate from a datagrid.

I assoume, that the binding has the wrong Path (WTimeClockOverviewVM instead of ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp).

However, when I try to bind the propertie, the datepicker control is empty.

The first binding (id) works successfully.

Does someone have any idea?

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="DgStempelungen"
    Margin="0 10 10 0"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserAddRows="True"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding TimeDetailList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding  Id}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="KOMMEN DATUM">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker Text="{Binding ComeBooking}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

VIEW MODEL

```
[CanBeNull] 
private ObservableCollection<ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp> _timeDetailList;

[CanBeNull]
public ObservableCollection<ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp> TimeDetailList
{
    get { return _timeDetailList; }
    set
    {
        _timeDetailList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
public class ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp
{
    public DateTime ComeBooking { get; set; }
    public DateTime GoBooking { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind `ComeBooking` to SelectedDate property like this

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding ComeBooking}"/>
```

To support changing DatePicker's SelectedDate from source, you ought to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class ClassTimeTrackingTimeStamp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _comeBooking;
    public DateTime ComeBooking
    {
        get => _comeBooking;
        set
        {
            _comeBooking = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    private DateTime _goBooking;
    public DateTime GoBooking
    {
        get => _goBooking;
        set
        {
            _goBooking = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Info { get; set; }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you. Now I can get the value. But how can I set the Comebooking. If I change the date, the date jumps back to the old date.

Comment: You mean when you change it from code it won't change on UI (I've updated the answer to support this)? or when you change it in UI it does not change at all?

Comment: It works with the propertyChanged. Thank you very much for your help :)